# Linkedin Community management API image upload permission issue

Tags: linkedin-api

I've a question regarding new community management API. I received standard tier access for our application and I changed old permissions r_organization_social, w_organization_social, w_member_social to new one r_organization_social_feed, w_organization_social_feed, w_member_social_feed.

When I try to create a post with image via API I get an error:

> Request Error: Not enough permissions to access:
> partnerApiImagesExternal.ACTION-initializeUpload.20230501.

Raw Response:

```
Array
(
[status] => 403
[serviceErrorCode] => 100
[code] => ACCESS_DENIED
[message] => Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiImagesExternal.ACTION-initializeUpload.20230501
).
```

When I use both old and new permissions set I'm able to upload image and create post successfully. Unfortunately at this point it is not clear how can I solve this permission issue.

Comment: can you share the code how to upload img and create post?